# When to reload sip

Tags: asterisk, sip, freepbx

I have faced this issue many times, when I call on my sip line the server responds that the line is busy, though no call is going on when I see with asterisk -vvvr command. When I reload it, it starts working.

Is there a way to troubleshoot this problem or at least get a trigger form some command that sip needs to be reloaded.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk work for years without reload.

Try update it to latest system or find bug in your config(like no dns, nat settings changed, bad router etc).

Asterisk have no any triggers for such case. You can use external monitoring system(like nagios) which will check sip channel and reload if needed. But better find issue and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Watch the CLI with a high debug/verbosity to see what's going wrong.

Set verbosity to a high value:
`core set verbose 10`

Set Debug to a high value:
`core set debug 10`

You can also check the status of the SIP endpoint with:
`sip show peer <extension>` (Replace  with the number you'd use to dial the endpoint).

If you add verbose CLI output and the output of `sip show peer` to your question we'll be able to tell you how to fix the issue. Use pastebin or a similar site if the output is very long.